# How to properly convert state in Class based components to use Hooks instead?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I keep getting `[object Object]` in my form input fields.

I have been trying to change the state of multiple elements with the useState() hook, but am struggling to have all of them in the same toggle function. Previously I had

```
state = {
  username: "Hunter",
  location: "",
  name: "",
  date: "today"
};

toggleAll = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
};
```

This worked fine. When I tried to convert it to Hooks like this

```
 const [username, setUsername] = useState("Hunter")
 const [location, setLocation] = useState("") 
 const [name, setName] = useState("") 
 const [date, setDate] = useState("today")
```

and update it in this way

```
function toggleAll(e) {
        const {name, value} = e.target 
        name === "location" ? setLocation({ [name]: value }) : 
        name === "name" ? setName({ [name]: value }) :
        name === "date" ? setDate({ [name]: value }) :
        setUsername({ [name]: value }) 
    }
```

It wouldn't work. In the input fields in my form, when I write, I get `[object Object]`. The radio buttons won't work as well.

Answer (score 4):

Your state values are not objects anymore, so you just need to set the `value`:

```
function toggleAll(e) {
        const {name, value} = e.target 
        name === "location" ? setLocation( value ) : 
        name === "name" ? setName( value ) :
        name === "date" ? setDate( value ) :
        setUsername( value ) 
    }
```

This looks like a good use case for [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook as an alternative to `useState`.

The advantage of using the reducer hook is that it's generally recommended when the app has complex state and it's more closely resembles the state structure you had before. Additionally if your action type names and input names are consistent `toggleAll` function will be more simple. The basic implementation may look smth like this:

```
const initialState = {
  username: "Hunter",
  location: "",
  name: "",
  date: "today"
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_USERNAME":
      return {
        ...state,
        username: action.payload
      };

    case "SET_LOCATION":
      return {
        ...state,
        location: action.payload
      };
    case "SET_NAME":
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.payload
      };
    case "SET_DATE":
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.payload
      };
  }
};


// Inside component 

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

function toggleAll(e) {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  const actionType = `SET_${name.toUpperCase()}`;
  dispatch({ type: actionType, payload: value });
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion with the useReducer hook!

Comment: how exactly would useReducer be used in this case and why is it a good use case?

Comment: @kiabbott i've updated the answer. Also remember to accept it if it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong is the syntax of setting the state, it is not like that anymore as compared to the setState of class components.
Just do it as:

```
function toggleAll(e) {
        const {name, value} = e.target 
        name === "location" ? setLocation(value) : 
        name === "name" ? setName(value) :
        name === "date" ? setDate(value) :
        setUsername(value) 
    }
```